# Split a list of tuples into sub-lists of the same tuple field

Tags: python, list, sorting, grouping

I have a huge list of tuples in this format. The second field of the each tuple is the category field.

```
    [(1, 'A', 'foo'),
    (2, 'A', 'bar'),
    (100, 'A', 'foo-bar'),

    ('xx', 'B', 'foobar'),
    ('yy', 'B', 'foo'),

    (1000, 'C', 'py'),
    (200, 'C', 'foo'),
    ..]
```

What is the most efficient way to break it down into sub-lists of the same category ( A, B, C .,etc)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools
import operator

data=[(1, 'A', 'foo'),
    (2, 'A', 'bar'),
    (100, 'A', 'foo-bar'),

    ('xx', 'B', 'foobar'),
    ('yy', 'B', 'foo'),

    (1000, 'C', 'py'),
    (200, 'C', 'foo'),
    ]

for key,group in itertools.groupby(data,operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print(list(group))
```

yields

```
[(1, 'A', 'foo'), (2, 'A', 'bar'), (100, 'A', 'foo-bar')]
[('xx', 'B', 'foobar'), ('yy', 'B', 'foo')]
[(1000, 'C', 'py'), (200, 'C', 'foo')]
```

Or, to create one list with each group as a sublist, you could use a list comprehension:

```
[list(group) for key,group in itertools.groupby(data,operator.itemgetter(1))]
```

---

The second argument to `itertools.groupby` is a function which `itertools.groupby` applies to each item in `data` (the first argument). It is expected to return a `key`. `itertools.groupby` then groups together all contiguous items with the same `key`.

[operator.itemgetter(1)](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) picks off the second item in a sequence.

For example, if

```
row=(1, 'A', 'foo')
```

then

```
operator.itemgetter(1)(row)
```

equals `'A'`.

---

As @eryksun points out in the comments, if the categories of the tuples appear in some random order, then you must sort `data` first before applying `itertools.groupby`. This is because `itertools.groupy` only collects **contiguous** items with the same key into groups.

To sort the tuples by category, use:

```
data2=sorted(data,key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: Don't forget that the data first has to be sorted: `data2 = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(1))`.

Comment: Great answer, don't forget that you can use a lambda instead of the operator, for folks who are used to lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

#### [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

`itertools.groupby` requires the input to be sorted by the key field, otherwise you will have to sort *first*, incurring O(*n* log *n*) cost. For guaranteed O(*n*) time complexity, you can use a `defaultdict` of lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    dd[item[1]].append(item)

res = list(dd.values())

print(res)

[[(1, 'A', 'foo'), (2, 'A', 'bar'), (100, 'A', 'foo-bar')],
 [('xx', 'B', 'foobar'), ('yy', 'B', 'foo')],
 [(1000, 'C', 'py'), (200, 'C', 'foo')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get multiple lists of singletons from a list of tuples:

```
foo = ((1,2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7,8) , (9, 10))
[[z[i] for z in foo] for i in (0,1)]
```

If you prefer to get multiple tuples of singletons:

```
zip(*[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)])
```