# Extract the tuple with the largest item from sublist (find most recent report in directory)

Tags: python, tuples

I have a script that creates a directory listing of all pdfs within a certian series of subdirectories.  The outputs are tuples that include the year of the file saved as a string as well as an id for the unit that generated the report that looks something like the following:

```
unit1, 2010
unit2, 2002
unit2, 2005
unit2, 2010 
unit3, 2003
```

What I'm looking to now do is create a report that finds the most recent report based on the tuple that contains the max value in its second item.  Normally, I would do this in Access with a MAX query, however, I am trying to elimate that step since and write the extract all at once.  Using my orginal code, my output would consist of the following:

```
unit1, '2010'
unit2, '2010'
unit3, '2003'
```

I did some looking around and realize that I need to change my script so that it would generate a list of the tuples that matched every unique id.  Using the great answer I found  from [Split a list of tuples into sub-lists of the same tuple field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092877/split-a-list-of-tuples-into-sub-lists-of-the-same-tuple-field) I was able to get the results split into a group of sublists.  This means my output is now the following:

```
[[(unit1, '2010')],[(unit12, '2010'), (unit2, '2010'), (unit2, '2005'), (unit2, '2002')],[(unit3, '2003']]
```

My difficulty now is trying to extract the tuple from each sublist that contains the highest value item.  I tried the following:

```
import glob, os, itertools, operator  
dirtup = []
for f in glob.glob('P:\Office*\Technical*\Bureau*\T*\*\YR2*\R*\*\*.pdf'):
    fpath, fname = os.path.split(f)
    fyr = fpath[91:95]
    vcs = 'Volume'
    rname, extname = os.path.splitext(fname)
    rcid = fname[0:7]
    dirtup.append ((f, fyr, rcid, vcs))

dirtup2 = sorted(dirtup, key=operator.itemgetter(2))

for key, group in itertools.groupby(dirtup2, operator.itemgetter(2)):
    maxval = max(x[1] for x in dirtup2)

print [x for x in dirtup2 if x[1] == maxval]
```

This returns only the tuple that match the max of fyr rather then the max of fyr per each sublist.

**Edit**

Using mglison's first answer I was able to get the output (tuple that contained second item with max value).

Comment: @selllikesybok thanks for cleaning up the code

Comment: I've edited this again to try to make question a little more clear: I like to use print to verify things before I worry about writting the results to file but that means on occasion I can get a bit lost.  If I'm passing results between for statments it's not a good idea to get fixated on only one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort each sublist based on the particular field and take the first element of the sorted sublist.

```
for key,group in itertools.groupby(dirtup2,operator.itemgetter(2)):
    newlist=sorted(group,key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
    tuple_with_max=newlist[0]
    print tuple_with_max
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand how the second line's iteration through the sublist works.

Comment: @mburkenysdot -- I'm sorry.  I don't understand your question.  Could you try again?

Comment: @mburkenysdot -- I've updated my answer.  I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but I guessed.  Let me know if this does or doesn't work.

Comment: I just wanted to say I very much appericate the help you've given me (this is the second question you've provided a helpful answer).

Comment: --the appolgies belong on my end.  Hopefully I made myself more clear as to what I'm going for in my edits to the orginal question.

Comment: @mburkenysdot -- check my edit.  My original version looked a little closer to what you wanted so I rolled it back and updated.  Does this do what you want?